# XAMPP any special requirement on the password/salt length setting?

Tags: php, xampp

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBgZl.png)

Hi, I am learning the XAMPP and creating the database of users. And on the user's password and salt, I am confused. Teacher said salt length should be same as the password length. For example, if I set password length max to be 20, then salt should be 20 too. But under my testing of inserting password data into the database. no matter how salt length changes, echo encryptedPassword($password . $salt), the length is always 40. And if I set password length in database less than 40, it cannot insert the encryptedPassword into database password. I must adjust the database password length to 40 or more, then inserting data can work. So is it because salt length always keep 40? Then password length in database must be more than/equal to 40?

```
PHP code 
$email = htmlentities($_REQUEST['email']);
$firstName = htmlentities($_REQUEST['firstName']);
$lastName = htmlentities($_REQUEST['lastName']);
$password = htmlentities($_REQUEST['password']);
$birthday = htmlentities($_REQUEST['birthday']);
$gender = htmlentities($_REQUEST['gender']);

$salt = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(20);
$encryptedPassword = sha1($password . $salt);
```

Comment: You really shouldn't use that method. Look at the functions `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` as these are more widely recommended now.

Comment: I think what your teacher mean is that every password char should have char at salt same position, so salt does not get rotated inside hashing algorithm. But in real life scenario you do not use salt at all. You use `password_hash`

Comment: As for your actual question, many of these hash results are a fixed length regardless of the length of the string you put in. If you read up on sha1, that produces a 20-byte hash which is generally used in displayable format as a 40-character hex string. Hence the result of your code is always 40 characters long, yes.

Comment: This is a realy bad implementation. Why woul you store the salt within the user password ? Its (not exactly) the same as store the password in plain text...

Comment: Could someone recommend me any book about this knowledge, I need to read some book to learn the full version, is it belonging to SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the image attached to the question, you are attempting to store the (assumedly) user-entered password in the database. This makes the hashing absolutely nugatory as the whole point of generating a password hash is to secure the password in the case of database intrusions.

In your case, if you insist on using the `sha1()` function to generate the hash, I suggest you drop the `password` column from your table and add a new column which stores strings of 40-character length to store your hash.